# Executing wx.Frame inside def?

Tags: wxpython

I'm writing a GUI for the Xboxdrv Package inside Linux. I want people to be able to use this GUI to configure their Xbox360, PS3 or any other type of controller as a mouse, game pad, etc. inside Linux.

I'm curious how you can call a function from a GUI action.

So for example, I click a menu button that I created and it calls an function stored in my wx.Frame.

Comment: If you could post some of the code you've already written it will help us to better understand what your question.

Comment: def Here(self,event):
    class XBOX(wx.Frame):
          def __init__(self,parent,id):
              wx.frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'XboxDrv ManPage',size=(300,200))
                 app = wx.App()
                 app.MainLoop()

Comment: Sorry About Sloppy Code I Couldnt Post It Right In The Comment Box.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem, you create a menu item and you want to know how to execute a function when a user clicks it.

This is pretty simple. You need the `self.Bind()` function. Look at this:

```
ID_MY_MENU_FUNCTION = wx.NewId() #declares a new, unique ID for my menu

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, idNum, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, idNum, title)

        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(ID_MY_MENU_FUNCTION, 'My Function') #add my function to the menu

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.Append(menu, 'My Menu') #add my menu to the menu bar

        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar) #set the menu bar

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.myFunction, id=ID_My_MEN_FUNCTION) #run self.myFunction() when someone clicks the menu item

    def myFunction(event):
        #perform your function here
```

When calling `self.Bind()` setting the `id` argument is important. This means `self.myFunction()` will ONLY be called if the `wx.EVT_MENU` has the same ID as the `id` argument. Also, each menu item needs it's own unique ID or else your application won't be able to tell which menu item the user clicked.

It is also very important that in `self.Bind()`, when saying which function you want to bind the event to you include `self` BUT DO NOT INCLUDE `()`. That's why I wrote `self.myFunction`.

Finally, notice how I defined my method of `myFunctio(event)`. This is also important. When a function is bound to an event, the event is always passed as the first argument to that function. You need to be able to handle this.

You can find a very good tutorial [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#wx.MenuBar).

Good luck!

Comment: Ahhhhh Thank You So Much Man.
That Helped Alot.
I Did What You Said.
I Left The Id Out And When Adding The ID It Worked.
thanks For Helping A Noob Like Me.
im still learning programming GUI's

Comment: @enjoipython Ya, the IDs are important because there are many menu items, all of which cause `wx.EVT_MENU` so you need to be able to tell which menu item was clicked. Glad I could help.